# How to fetch the deleted records?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How to fetch the deleted records. I am using Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a backup before the deletion? ...or you could try using flashback (SELECT AS OF)

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01003

Hope I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Lenny Edwards

Answer (score -1):

Do some research into the `RETURNING` clause: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#BABHDGIG

The link has a fully-functional example with an `UPDATE` statement.  I'm sure if you spent some time on it you can figure out how to make it work with a `DELETE` statement as well.

```
DECLARE
   TYPE EmpRec IS RECORD (last_name   employees.last_name%TYPE, 
                          salary      employees.salary%TYPE);
   emp_info EmpRec;
   emp_id   NUMBER := 100;
BEGIN
   UPDATE employees SET salary = salary * 1.1 WHERE employee_id = emp_id
      RETURNING last_name, salary INTO emp_info;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Just gave a raise to ' || emp_info.last_name ||
      ', who now makes ' || emp_info.salary);
   ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Comment: Not sure the reason for the downvote.  The original request isn't too clear, but when I hear "fetch deleted records", I'm thinking about knowing which records were just deleted.  For that, the RETURNING command is perfect for that.